# My ubuntu 20.04 LTS Freeze many times a day. Keyboard and mouse is unresponisve at this time. only soultion is power on button means hard reset

Tags: 20.04, freeze, disk-usage, disk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZPZS.png)

df -h command output is:

```
bhaveshk@linux:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  2.3M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda6        19G  4.3G   14G  25% /
/dev/sda11       46G   12G   32G  28% /usr
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda7       4.6G  229M  4.1G   6% /boot
/dev/sda9        46G   17G   27G  40% /var
/dev/loop0      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop1       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1974
/dev/loop2      119M  119M     0 100% /snap/core/15511
/dev/loop4       74M   74M     0 100% /snap/core22/817
/dev/loop7      219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/93
/dev/loop3       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2785
/dev/loop12      38M   38M     0 100% /snap/hunspell-dictionaries-1-7-2004/2
/dev/loop19      54M   54M     0 100% /snap/snapd/19457
/dev/loop15     321M  321M     0 100% /snap/vlc/3078
/dev/loop18      13M   13M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/959
/dev/loop8      350M  350M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143
/dev/loop11     176M  176M     0 100% /snap/mysql-workbench-community/12
/dev/loop16     348M  348M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-runtime/349
/dev/loop5      246M  246M     0 100% /snap/firefox/2908
/dev/loop9       37M   37M     0 100% /snap/heroku/4092
/dev/loop17     304M  304M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-5-stable/18
/dev/loop20     323M  323M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-6-stable/19
/dev/loop13      92M   92M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop10     486M  486M     0 100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/120
/dev/loop14     117M  117M     0 100% /snap/robo3t-snap/9
/dev/loop6      165M  165M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198
/dev/sda10       46G  281M   43G   1% /opt
/dev/sda14      153G   97G   48G  67% /home
/dev/sda12       46G  9.7M   44G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda15      274G   28K  260G   1% /data
/dev/sda1       146M   89M   58M  61% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G   72K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

moved from comment:

```
bhaveshk@linux:~$ free -h 
total used free shared buff/cache available 
Mem: 15Gi 12Gi 415Mi 1.2Gi 2.4Gi 1.4Gi 
Swap: 2.0Gi 0B 2.0Gi
```

==> just i have created swap to 2GB.

Comment: System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab fallocate` to create some. Swap space must be contiguous. use `mkswap` or `fallocate`, not `dd`. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: bhaveshk@linux:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi        12Gi       415Mi       1.2Gi       2.4Gi       1.4Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi        ==> just i have created swap to 2GB.